# How to prepend a hashtag in EditText on user's typing

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have problem for creating hashTag in editext.

Following are my requirements

1.Whenever user start type it starts with hash. If user type 'G' then it will be '#g' similar for whole word.

2.After typing word and user enter space and type 'T' then '#t'.

I have tried using text change listner but it not working for me.

I have tried using textwatcher:

```
tt = object:TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                edtTags.setSelection(s.length)
            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, count:Int, after:Int) {}
            override  fun onTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, before:Int, count:Int) {
                edtTags.removeTextChangedListener(tt)
                edtTags.setText(edtTags.getText().toString().replace(" ", " #"))
                edtTags.addTextChangedListener(tt)
            }
        }
        edtTags.addTextChangedListener(tt)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, on a similar case:

```kotlin
        var isSelfChanging = false
        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                if (!isSelfChanging) {
                    isSelfChanging = true

                    val formattedText = ("#" + s.toString()) // adds a hashtag in start
                        .replaceFirst("##", "#") // removes initial hashtag if needed
                        .replace(" #", " ") // removes all hashtag at the begging of words
                        .replace(Regex(" (\\S)"), " #$1") // re-adds the hashtags at the begging of words
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()) // forces lowercase
                    if (s.toString() != formattedText) {
                        s?.replace(0, s.length, formattedText, 0, formattedText.length)
                    }
                    isSelfChanging = false
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                // nothing
            }
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                // nothing
            }
        })
    }
```

It isn't perfect, specially if the user tries to edit the middle of the text, but most autocompletes don't work well in this scenario